# Showing Toast in fragments

Tags: android, fragment, onclicklistener, android-toast

I want to show toast on button `click`, and that button is in the fragment. I have tried methods to get context for the `toast`, but it is not showing on button click.

**This is my code**

```
public class Bottom_Sheet_Fragment extends Fragment {

Button addComment;

public Bottom_Sheet_Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom__sheet, container, false);

    addComment=(Button) container.findViewById(R.id.addCommentBtn);
    addComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
  }
}
```

This is fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/commentList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etComment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:hint="Write comment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addCommentBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Add" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this layout file is included in another activity, with in include statement.dont know where is the problem. and this fragment works like a bottomsheet.

Comment: tried adding some `Log.d` inside `onClick` and watch the logcat?

Comment: You need to call `findViewById()` on `view`, not `container`. I'm surprised that's not crashing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MikeM. I bet it does - but he decide to not write about it ... eventually, this is not the fragment which he is using ..... **or .... containter contains another button with the same id but he is clicking the one from fragment**

Comment: @Mike M. i also tried 'findViewById' with view.but still it is not working.

Comment: @Selvin my application is not crashing.

Comment: Then the problem is not here...

Comment: so what do you see on the logcat? do you see the `Log.d` you added inside `onClick` method?

Comment: log message is not displaying.it means onclick is not working

Comment: so try to add `Log.d` before calling `addComment.setOnClickListener`, do you see it now?

Comment: no.still not showing

Comment: so your fragment is not added at all: `Fragment#onCreateView` method is not called, do you know how to [debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)?

Comment: and yes, it explains why your code didnt crash - once you add your fragment you will see the  beautiful crash due to `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `addComment = view.findViewById(R.id.addCommentBtn);`
Because you must get button from layout was inflated.

Comment: Check in fragment_bottom__sheet already contain addCommentBtn?

Comment: Show me layout file of fragment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166903/discussion-between-meoscoder-and-numrah).

Comment: posted my fragment layout file

Comment: So, where you put fragment in activity

Comment: in another activity layout file.i have sent you

Comment: I sent you, put <fragment> tag in layout of activity

Comment: You should create unique id for fragment android:id="@+id/fragment"

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `view.findViewById`.

**Try This**

```
addComment=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addCommentBtn);
addComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```